# Is there any Unit testing framework for(pipeline as code) GitHub actions based workflow

Tags: unit-testing, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Is there any testing framework available to write unit tests on the configuration and conditional logic of the GitHb actions based workflow (pipeline code), by providing a mock execution of the pipeline ?

Comment: I'm the same situation I know you can unit test jenkinsfiles sorta like this [here](https://downloads.ctfassets.net/vtn4rfaw6n2j/jenkinsworld2018-robustunit-testingofpipelinecodewithspock-austi/2e3b55dbb9e053208893bf0de39a7d85/jenkins_world_2018_-_robust_unit-testing_of_pipeline_code_with_spock_-_austin_witt.pdf) but I want this to work on validating GH workflows. maybe checks will do this ?